# Read binary into hex byte array

Tags: c++, arrays

How would do you read file byte for byte and save every byte in hex form in an array?
So it would look like this:

```
unsigned char binaryData[10] = {
    0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x4B
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `save every byte in hex form in an array` What do you mean by this?

Comment: `std::ifstream in{"file", std::ios::binary};`?

Comment: So I can read an executable and save it in a byte array

Comment: Bytes in memory aren't "in hex form" — that's just a way of displaying the values.  You can read data into a byte array, then convert the byte array into a hex string and print the string.

Comment: Do you want to populate an array at runtime, or are you trying to generate code so the array can be compiled into your code statically? If it's populated at runtime, are you okay with using types that aren't strictly arrays, but act like them (aside from managing memory allocation for you), or do you need to populate some fixed true array or manually manage your heap allocations yourself?

Comment: I am plannning to convert a binary to an array on a server, transmit it to a client via c++ winsock and execute that byte array on the client. The function I am currently using to execute byte arrays takes an unsigned char array as input.

Comment: BEWARE of security implications. This is literally RCE, be sure you know the implications and liability claims you may face if there is reckless neglect for security.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question should have been worded: *"how can I convert binary data into C++ source code defining an array that contains the same data."*

I think you will want to know about

```
xxd -i file.bin
```

For the above markdown it would emit:

```
unsigned char file_bin[] = {
  0x49, 0x20, 0x74, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x6b, 0x20, 0x79, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x20,
  0x77, 0x69, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x20, 0x77, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x20, 0x74, 0x6f,
  0x20, 0x6b, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x77, 0x20, 0x61, 0x62, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x74, 0x0a,
  0x0a, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x78, 0x78, 0x64, 0x20, 0x2d, 0x69, 0x20,
  0x66, 0x69, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x2e, 0x62, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x0a
};
unsigned int file_bin_len = 57;
```